# How to delete an object at specific index in a linked-list?

Tags: java

I saw there are some question about the subject but the situation here is a bit different, while the other questions deal with the Java linked-list class, this is a custom class that I got from my teacher with some specific attributes.

So what I need to do is to write a method called 'removeAt' that gets a 'int k' and remove the object at the 'k' index and return the 'data' item of the removed object...

my problem is that after finding the object I want to remove it (basically remove its pointer to the next list node..) and it feels like there are some missing attributes, and he did not say to add new ones.

this is my code:

```
public class List {

    private ListNode firstNode;
    private ListNode lastNode;
    private String name;


    public List()
    {
        this("list");
    }


    public List(String listName)
    {
        name=listName;
        firstNode=lastNode=null;
    }


    //override 
    public String toString()
    {
        String stringToReturn = "";

        ListNode currentNode = firstNode;

        while (currentNode != null) {

            stringToReturn += currentNode.toString();
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();

            if (currentNode != null) {
                stringToReturn += ", ";
            }
        }
        return stringToReturn;
    }


    public Object removeAt(int k) throws ListIndexOutOfBound
    {
        ListNode removedNode = this.firstNode;
        Object removedObject;
        int idx = 0;

        if (isEmpty())
            throw new EmptyListException(this.name);

        if (k < 0)
            throw new ListIndexOutOfBound();

        if (k == 0) {
            removedObject = this.removeFromFront();
        } else {

            while (idx != k) {
                removedNode = removedNode.getNext();
                idx++;

                if (removedNode == null)
                    throw new ListIndexOutOfBound();
            }

            if (removedNode == this.lastNode) {
                removedNode = (ListNode) this.removeFromBack();
            } else {
                removedObject = removedNode.data;
                //i'm stuck here...I want to remove this node from the list!

            }
        }
        return removedNode; 
    }
```

There is also a ListNode class that looks like this:

```
public class ListNode {

    Object data;
    ListNode nextNode;


    public ListNode(Object o){
        this(o,null);
    }
    public ListNode(Object o,ListNode node){
        data=o;
        nextNode=node;
    }
    public Object getObject(){
        return data;
    }
    public ListNode getNext(){
        return nextNode;
    }

}
```

How would you suggest to accomplish this?

Comment: Java has gc so just remove all references to it and your good. However, not all items are leafs. IOW, you have to deal with 1-2-3, where you want to remove 2. Think about it. Also, ask your teacher why you're not using generics.

Comment: How do i remove the reference to it? This is my question @ChiefTwoPencils

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to always remember the node before the node to remove in order to set the next node after removing the desired node:

```
    if (k == 0) {
        removedObject = this.removeFromFront();
    } else {

        ListNode prev = null;

        while (idx != k) {
            prev = removedNode;
            removedNode = removedNode.getNext();
            idx++;

            if (removedNode == null)
                throw new ListIndexOutOfBound();
        }

        if (removedNode == this.lastNode) {
            removedNode = (ListNode) this.removeFromBack();
        } else {
            removedObject = removedNode.data;
            prev.setNext(removedNode.getNext());
        }
    }
```

That means you'd have to add a method `setNext(ListNode next)` to the `ListNode` object.

```
    public void setNext(ListNode next){
        nextNode = next;
    }
```

What this does is setting `nextNode` of `prev` to `removedNode.getNext()`

```
|                |   prev.getNext()     | removedNode.getNext()    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| prev           |   removedNode        | <any node> or null       |
```

After:

```
|                |   prev.nextNode()    | (<any node>.nextNode())? |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| prev           |   <any node> or null | ...                      |
```

Comment: but in ListNode I have an attribute called 'nextNode', so can't I just say 'prev.nextNode = removedNode.getNext;' ? instead of creating a new method @StefanFalk

Comment: Well you can if it is `public`. In that case you would not need a `setNode(ListNode next)` method.