# Delete the last node of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, delete-operator

I am trying to delete the last Node of a linked list,
I have the first element of the list. But the function does not work I would be happy if you could help me

Code -

```
void deleteNode(Node* firstNode)
{
    Node* currNode = firstNode;
    while (currNode->next != NULL)
    {
     currNode = currNode->next;
    }
     delete currNode->next;
     currNode->next = NULL;
 }
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254001/how-to-delete-an-object-at-specific-index-in-a-linked-list/24254063#24254063

Comment: After you delete the correct node (currentNode instead of currentNode->next). Think about what will happen if you only have 1 node. Also I would change the name of this function to something similar to deleteLastNode()

Comment: You loop until `currNode->next` is `NULL`. Think about what happens next.

Comment: The program crashes at he while loop

Comment: The signature of the function needs to be either void `deleteNode(Node** firstNode)` or void `deleteNode(Node*& firstNode)`. You need to be able to modify `firstNode` pointer when the list has a single node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deleting the one after the last node, which should be NULL anyways.

```
void deleteNode(Node* firstNode)
{
    //first check if firstNode is NULL or last node.
    if(firstNode == NULL)
        return;

    if(firstNode->next == NULL)
    {
        delete firstNode;
        firstNode = NULL;
        return;
    }

    Node* currNode = firstNode;
    while (currNode->next && currNode->next->next != NULL)
    {
        currNode = currNode->next;
    }
    delete currNode->next;
    currNode->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: @user3742037 Note: this will *NOT* work if the list has only one element. The statement `firstNode = NULL;` is useless for clearing the *caller's* passed-in pointer to NULL in a single-element list. I suspect you'll discover this eventually, hopefully sooner rather than later.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are correct

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider a few things:

- Any operation that could potentially affect the head pointer *must* provide a mechanism for returning the updated head pointer (an in/out param i.e. pointer to pointer or reference-of-pointer, or by function return result; I prefer the former).
- Any pointer holding the address of the last node in the list, be it the head pointer or any other, *must* be set to NULL.

That said,

**Pointer To Pointer**

```
void deleteLastNode(Node** firstNode)
{
    while (*firstNode && (*firstNode)->next)
        firstNode = &(*firstNode)->next;
    free(*firstNode);   /**/
    *firstNode = NULL;  /**/
}
```

Note if the pointer passed in by-address is already NULL, *both* lines above marked with `/**/` need not be executed, but are harmless none-the-less, as `free()`-ing `NULL` is supported per the standard as a no-op.

Called by passing the address of the head pointer, the content of which **must** be `NULL` if the list is empty.

```
Node *head = NULL;
//... code to populate the list.

deleteLastNode(&head);
```

**Reference of Pointer**

With C++, you can also pass the head pointer by reference, for example:

```
void deleteLastNode(Node*& head)
{
    Node **firstNode = &head;
    while (*firstNode && (*firstNode)->next)
        firstNode = &(*firstNode)->next;
    free(*firstNode);   /**/
    *firstNode = NULL;  /**/
}
```

Invoked as:

```
Node *head = NULL;
//... code to populate the list.

deleteLastNode(head);
```

Which mechanism you choose is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting one after the final node.

```
delete currNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void deleteNode(Node *firstNode)
{
    Node* currNode = firstNode;
    Node* nextNode = firstNode->next;
    while(nextNode != NULL)
    {
        currNode = nextNode;
        nextNode = nextNode->next;
    }
    delete currNode;
}
```

Comment: This code has a problem, too - not as big as that in the original code, but it's there...

Comment: I'm sorry, we need to delete the current node since nextNode is NULL

Comment: First, you do not set a pointer of `next` to `NULL` upon deletion of the node. This sets you up for trouble the next time you walk the list.

Comment: Second, you do not handle the situation when `firstNode` is the only node there. In fact, the signature of the function is wrong, because it cannot possibly handle removals from a single-node list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, at the last instance curNode points to the last node of the list. When you delete the curNode, you will no longer be left with node, ie, the data and next part. So you now you cannot access next part of curNode. This code will lead to runtime error:

```
currNode->next = NULL;
```

Instead try this:

If the list contains only one element, then firstNode points to NULL and the only node is deleted. If there are more than two items in your list, your have to iterate to the last second element, set its next value to NULL, and delete the last node with the help of a temp pointer.

```
void pop_back(struct node** firstNode)
{
    struct node* p = *firstNode;

    if(p == NULL) 
        cout << "List empty." << endl;

    else if(p->next == NULL){
        cout << "Element " << p-> data << " deleted." << endl;
        delete *firstNode;
        *firstNode = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        while(p->next->next != NULL){
            p= p->next;
        }

    struct node* temp = p-> next;
    p->next = NULL;
    cout << "Element " << temp->data << " deleted." << endl;
    delete temp; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void delBottom()
{
    clrscr();
    Node *nb=H;              //current
    Node *nn=(H->getNext()); //next
    if(NULL==H)
    {
        cout<<"List Empty";
    }
    else if(H==T)
    {
        delete H;  //H-Head
        H=T=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(NULL!=(nn->getNext()))
        {
            nb=nn;
            nn=nn->getNext();
        }
        delete nn;
        nb->setNext(NULL);
        T=nb;  //T-Tail
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

actually, you should write like this:

```
void deleteNode(Node* firstNode)
{
    Node* currNode = firstNode;
    while (currNode->next != NULL)
    {
     currNode = currNode->next;
    }
     ***delete currNode;
     currNode = NULL;***
 }
```

cause, currNode is the last node.